# What is the expected number of poisoned individuals after $10$ rounds of shaking hands?

Tags: probability, statistics

There are $1000$ individuals labeled $1-1000$. Initially, Number $1$ is poisoned.

Each round there will be $500$ pairs of people shaking hands. Each round, a perfect matching between the $1000$ participants is selected uniformly at random among all such matchings that don't contain a handshake that has already occurred. If an individual shakes hands with a poisoned person, she becomes poisoned, too.

After $10$ rounds, what is, approximately, the expected number of poisoned individuals?

For example, if there are $8$ people in total, Number $1$ is poisoned. In the first round, $1$ shakes hands with $2$ and they are both poisoned. In the next round, $1$ and $2$ cannot shake hands again, so $1$ shakes hands with $3$ and $2$ shakes hands with $4$. In the next round, there are several options. For instance, $1,2,3,4$ can shake hands with $5,6,7,8$ respectively, which would spread the poison to all $8$ participants; or $1$ can shake hands with $4$, $2$ with $3$, with $5,6,7,8$ pairing up somehow, which would keep the poison still among the $4$.

Comment: What do you mean by "estimation"? The expected value? If so, we need to know the distribution of the handshakes.

Comment: Which means the approximate number of expected value, not need to be exact, can be a range.

Comment: So you mean an estimate of the expected value? Then we also need to know the distribution of the handshakes.

Comment: People who choose randomly with others they never shake with...So the distribution will be close to uniform but not exact uniform.

Comment: It's not clear what that means exactly. A handshake involves two people. If each person uniformly randomly choses a partner they haven't shaken hands with yet, the result would be twice as many handshakes as needed, with potentially different numbers of handshakes per person. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Xiaonan If you clear up how the random shaking of hands works (is it possible in one round for a person to shake hands with many different individuals, if they all randomly choose her?) then your question will be clear. Otherwise, it must be closed.

Comment: @snoram Your edit hasn't really clarified the question (even assuming that you correctly divined the OP's intentions). It sounds as if each person shakes hands once per round, but the effect would be that the selected partners shake hands more than once. A clearer formulation of this interpretation of the original question would be that each round everyone *selects* someone whose hands to shake. This would be compatible with shaking hands both as a selecter and as a selectee.

Comment: Hi, so random means you will pick up a person randomly but that does not mean one person can shake hands with many people in one round. You can think each time there are two sets of bipartite graph, each node will have exact one edge from the other set.

Comment: @Xiaonan: It seems that you don't understand the problem. The two things you're saying are contradictory. If each person randomly picks one person whose hands they then shake, then inevitably the average number of handshakes per person will be $2$, not $1$. If there are $n$ people, they make $n$ selections, and each selection leads to two handshakes, one by the selecter and one by the selectee, for a total of $2n$ handshakes, an average of $2$ per person.

Comment: Let me give you an example, so in Round 0, there are 1 poison people. In Round 1, poison people will shake hands with one people who are not poison. So the total number of poison people will be 2. In Round 2, they will both have the ability to poison others, and they will never shake again because they already did, so in this round will result 4. In Round 3, the final result can be from 4-8. Is this a little bit more clear?

Comment: @Xiaonan: No, unfortunately it's not more clear. There is still nothing in what you've said that constitutes a consistent prescription for how the handshakes are chosen.

Comment: You can think a very famous problem as an instance: How many hands are shaking between 10 people and they need to shake their hands with each other once.

Comment: Random means randomly pick from those people who you have not shake your hands with and it will be a perfect match in the social network graph.

Comment: There are already four close votes, three of them for lack of clarity. With one more close vote, the question will be closed. I suggest that you think carefully about the contradiction I've pointed out and then formulate a consistent prescription for the selection of handshakes.

Comment: I think after my edit the problem is clear... and it still seems consistent with what the OP is saying -- still not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @snoram: I pointed out above why it's still not clear. If it's clarified in the way I suggested above ("selects" instead of "shakes"), it would be incompatible with what the OP has stated above: "that does not mean one person can shake hands with many people in one round".

Comment: Maybe if I stated each round they will be perfect match, then it will be more clear?

Comment: @joriki But as far as I can tell there is only one handshake per person per round -- so I think of pairs just forming randomly (except pairs from previous rounds can't shake hands again).

Comment: @joriki: We can probably assume that an omniscient master of ceremonies selects uniformly between all the perfect matchings between the 1000 participants that don't contain an already-used handshake. In any case, since only an approximation was asked for, I think the exact realization of the condition has minor significance.

Comment: @snoram: The formal problem with "pairs just forming randomly" is that you may end up with only two people left, and they have already shaken hands!

Comment: That can happen. But isn't that just a fun complexity of the problem?

Comment: @snoram: No, it makes the problem ill-defined. (Also there's no prescription in which order pairs should be formed.)

Comment: @snoram: No -- it's a situation _where the problem doesn't specify what happens_.

Comment: It is at least more or less defined: pairs are selected at random. If assumptions need to be made they can be made and then we can check for sensitivity of the results to the assumptions. An example: To form the first pair you draw and individual at random, and then you draw a second individual until you have a pair that hasen't shaked hands before. If it is impossible to find, you throw the first invidual out of the pool and start over again...

Comment: @Xiaonan: The question has now been put on hold due to lack of clarity. Please note that the first edit you now make will automatically put the question into the reopen queue. Thus, that edit is your best chance to have the question reopened; subsequent edits are much less likely to draw sufficient attention to collect the required reopen votes. I'd suggest to think through the issues raised in the comments and then make a single edit that resolves them.

Comment: @snoram, I don't think it is impossible to find. Think a bipartite graph, $n$ nodes in a set, $n$ nodes in another, you can come up with $n$ pairs of perfect matching.

Comment: @Xiaonan: Unfortunately your edit hasn't resolved the unclarity. The only consistent suggestion for a resolution that's been offered so far is the one by Henning, of uniformly randomly selecting among all the perfect matchings between the $1000$ participants that don't contain an already-used handshake.

Comment: @Xiaonan: Since your edit to include Henning's suggestion had provided a clear definition at one point in the question, I edited the question to clarify the other parts accordingly. I hope it now expresses what you intended to ask. (I also removed my downvote and voted to reopen.)

Comment: @joriki, the random, round-by-round construction sounds like it's constructing a round-robin tournament, at random, on the fly.  Is it obvious that, having randomly constructed the first nine rounds, it's always possible to extend it to a tenth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since only an approximation is required, we can probably ignore the requirement that each potential handshake may happen only once. After all, this won't even exclude one percent of each person's possible partners in any of the $10$ rounds.

Then, if $x$ infected persons after round $n$, the expected number of infected persons in the next round should be $x+x\frac{1000-x}{1000}$ (namely, there will be $x$ persons shaking hand with someone who is infected, and if they are randomly chosen, the proportion of them who are *not* infected is about $\frac{1000-x}{1000}$.

Iterating the map $x\mapsto x+x\frac{1000-x}{1000}$ ten times starting at $1$ gives
$$ 641.03 $$
which is probably a good ballpark estimate of how many infected can be expected after $10$ random handshake rounds. (But don't take this more seriously than "probably around 640, give or take a few dozen", or even "most likely somewhere between 600 and 700"; there are many approximations made along the way).

---

I did a Monte Carlo simulation of the problem; here are the final number of infected in 64 runs of the problem:

```
660  678  620  666  672  654  636  634  592  638  622  684  620  682  630  608
634  676  684  662  642  656  646  652  646  706  634  668  634  674  648  658
620  626  646  680  614  670  680  644  602  608  634  648  648  656  660  638
664  652  660  628  666  626  674  646  642  662  644  598  658  646  660  678
```

Over $1000$ runs I got a sample mean of $646.9$ and a standard deviation of $22.4$.

If I allow reused handshakes I get a mean of $642.5$ and standard deviation of $23.3$. As expected, this does not make much of a difference.

Comment: upper bound must be 2^10 = 1024.. since there is only one handshake each round number of infected can not more than double each round...

Comment: @snoram: It doesn't more than double; it's $x\mapsto2x-\frac{x^2}{1000}$. (Also obviously $641.03\lt1024$.)

Comment: @snoram, It is very rare to happen for $1024$ because poison people can shake hands with poison people which is a large chance as the round goes. Also, the purpose of this problem is to do the estimation, so the more tighter the bound is, the better it is.

Comment: $1000$ is a better upper bound than $1024$, since there cannot be more infected people than there are people. :-)

Comment: Regarding the function used, since an infected person cannot shake hands with him- or herself, the probability of newly infecting someone would actually be $\frac{1000 - x}{999}$.  This would push up the estimate ever-so-slightly to 642.98.